# What is this Kanji and where is it used in?

Tags: kanji

I found [this Kanji](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owWU8.png) online, what is it and what does it mean?

Is this a Japanese Kanji?

Comment: If there's meant to be an image, it didn't upload correctly.

Comment: I noticed that :/ Now it did though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character is 真{しん}　where しん (shin) is the on'yomi.  It's also has the kun'yomi readings of ま or まこと (ma *and* makoto).  It means *truth*.

Some examples of words using this character are: 真{ま}ん中{なか} meaning *right in the middle*.   Or, 真理{しんり} meaning *truth*.  Or, 真珠{しんじゅ} meaning *pearl*.  写真{しゃしん} means *photograph*.

So, as you can see it is used in a wide array of words.